# I am Not able to find JRE files in Program Files?

Tags: java

I am trying to download jdk in my windows 10 64 bit OS system. Once installation is completed I try to set the path. But I am not able to find the jre files in Program Files. But I want to jdk and jre both files to be in the Program files. In my colleagues systems jdk is installed in program files. In their system both files in Program Files like following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0_51
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8.0_251
```

But in my system files look like following.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
```

The path should be my colleagues format. Please help me on this.

Comment: There is no JRE for Java 9 and later.  Everything is in the JDK tree.  Your colleagues format **will not work** for Java 14.  Your PATH should just contain "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin" if you are using Java 14, and the JAVA_PATH should be  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2".

Comment: Alternatively download and use a Java 8 JDK distro ... which will have both the JDK and JRE files,

Comment: Note that the Oracle installation instructions for Java on Windows will explain what you need to do to install and setup Java.  Read them carefully and follow them accurately and you should be fine ... assuming that you *understand* how Windows environment variables work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your colleague is using JDK 8.

Download Oracle JDK 8(LTS) for here.

https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html.

Or you can use Amazon Corretto JDK 8 which is a nice choice as it automatically set environment for you. Just install, develop and run applications.

**Now, JDK comes with JRE included. So, you don't need to install JRE on your system.**

Set the `JAVA_HOME` to `<path of jdk>/bin` or `JRE_HOME` to `<path of jdk>/jre`

That's all.